# How to get other user information with apple signin

Tags: ios, apple-sign-in

My App required user email, phone number and City for providing the local discount offer. This is the paid app and we will charge differently in different cities according to the number of discounts we offer in that city. But know we are using apple sign-in which does not return any of these data. so we will add the separate form for getting this information after sign-in but apple will reject that by saying

> Sign in with Apple is designed to be a self-contained, all-in-one
> login system. With security features like built-in two-factor
> authentication, you can remove additional sign-up steps so users can
> focus on your app's content and features.

How I solve this issue?

Comment: Did you find any solution on this?